# Разрушение памяти в win64 программе?

Tags: delphi

есть код

```
procedure FindBestSubtree(DerevoIdx: Integer);
var
*объявление локальных переменных, среди них*
CurrentHashs: THashItem; // мой класс
begin
if Assigned(CurrentHashs) then // тут уже срабатывает
        writelog('Abnormal CurrentHashs', wlCritical);
end;
```

Показывает, что объект уже создан (и в отладчике даже какие-то данные видны)!
Программа многопоточная.
Раньше было нормально, начиная с какого-то момента (после форматирования кода?) внезапно стала появляться ошибка (на данный момент только при первом заходе в процедуру). Проблема появилась на совсем ровном месте. Грешу на SSD Samsung 860 QVO диск (явных ошибок нет, но несколько раз были замечены странности в виде временной замены "," на "." в большом csv файле).[image: настройки сборки проекта]

Delphi XE6, win 8.1. При сборке под win32 проблема пропадает (почти всегда). **Не понимаю куда смотреть**.

Добавка: Судя по всему локальные переменные процедур не инициализируются автоматически никогда и никакие (кроме может строк?). Иногда при компиляции может совпасть так, что в переменных может быть 0, но это не гарантирирует, что при следующей компиляции и запуске в не инициализированной переменной тоже будет 0.

Comment: Кода очень мало, не видно ни как создается объект, ни как используется. Могу посоветовать после `begin` добавить `CurrentHashs:=nil`. А освобождать обект через `FreeAndNil(CurrentHashs)`. И "почти всегда" это не показатель, все равно не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Локальные переменные надо инициализировать перед использованием. Иначе в них будет мусор, с чем вы и столкнулись.

В вашем примере вы объявили `CurrentHashs` и не проинициализировав его пытаетесь использовать. Функция `Assigned` просто сравнивает аргумент с `nil`, но раз мусор это не nil, вот и получается *"Abnormal CurrentHashs"*.